# Android app stalls when implementing SQLite database

Tags: java, android, sqlite

At first the app would just crash when I started it with an emulator, Not sure what I changed to get it to run but now it will run the onCreate method however, when I implement the addButtonClicked method the app just stalls and the Android Monitor displays "Suspending all threads" every few seconds and I'm not sure where to even begin debugging. Any pointers in the right direction would be greatly appreciated as I'm fairly new to Android development.

MainActivity.java

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

EditText testInput;
TextView testText;
MyDBHandler dbHandler;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    testInput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.testInput);
    testText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.testText);
    dbHandler = new MyDBHandler(this, null, null, 1);

    printDatabase();
}
//Add product to database

public void addButtonClicked(View view){
    Products product = new Products((testInput.getText().toString()));
    dbHandler.addProduct(product);
    printDatabase();
}

// Delete Items

public void deleteButtonClicked(View view){
    String inputText = testText.getText().toString();
    dbHandler.deleteProduct(inputText);
    printDatabase();
}


public void printDatabase(){
    String dbString = dbHandler.databaseToString();
    testText.setText(dbString);
    testInput.setText("");
}
}
```

Products.java

```
public class Products {
private int _id;
private String _productname;

public Products(){
}

public Products(String productname) {
    this._productname = productname;
}

public void set_id(int _id) {
    this._id = _id;
}

public void set_productname(String _productname) {
    this._productname = _productname;
}

public int get_id() {
    return _id;
}

public String get_productname() {
    return _productname;
}

}
```

MyDBHandler.java

```
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.ContentValues;

public class MyDBHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 15;
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "products.db";
public static final String TABLE_PRODUCTS = "products";
public static final String COLUMN_ID = "_id";
public static final String COLUMN_PRODUCTNAME = "productname";

public MyDBHandler(Context context, String name, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, factory, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String query = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_PRODUCTS +"(" +
            COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT ," +
            COLUMN_PRODUCTNAME +" TEXT " +
            ");";

    db.execSQL(query);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_PRODUCTS);
    onCreate(db);
}

//Add new row to the database
public void addProduct(Products product){
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(COLUMN_PRODUCTNAME, product.get_productname());
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
    db.insert(TABLE_PRODUCTS, null, values);
    db.close();
}

//Delete product from database
public void deleteProduct(String productName){
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
    db.execSQL("DELETE FROM " + TABLE_PRODUCTS + " WHERE " + COLUMN_PRODUCTNAME + "=\"" + productName + "\";" );
}

//Print of DB as sting
public String databaseToString(){
    String dbString = "";
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
    String query = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_PRODUCTS + " WHERE 1";

    //Cursor point to a location in your results
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery(query, null);
    //Move to the first row in your results
    c.moveToFirst();

    while (!c.isAfterLast()){
       if(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("productname"))!= null){
           dbString += c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("productname"));
           dbString += "\n";
       }
    }
    db.close();
    return dbString;
}


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for your databaseToString method you are performing a retrieve operation. You should be doing a read operation in a thread other than UI thread. Try fetching in AsyncTask. It should work. Implementation for your databaseToString should be handled by AsyncTask.

Happy Coding..

Comment: Thank you for your answer! That makes sense, how would I go about doing that?